# Reference a table by caption created by ctable

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing, captions, ctable

> Fixed in the new version of `ctable`
>
> [ctan-ann: CTAN Update: ctable](http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/msg04876.html) 26 May 2012

Might be a stupid question, but is there a way to reference, that means print, the caption of a ctable? `hyperref` has `\nameref` for sections, which works for normal floats, but not for `ctable`. This error is raised:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@safe@activesfalse \@ctblcap
\relax
l.92 ...kewed towards commodity. \nameref{tab:ef4}
```

Min example:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper, 12pt, DIV12, BCOR10mm, bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt} %DIV, BCOR =Seitenränder
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\ref{tab:table} %ok
\ref{tab:ctable} %ok
\autoref{tab:table} %ok
\autoref{tab:ctable} %ok
\nameref{tab:table} %ok 
\nameref{tab:ctable} %error


\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l}
hallo & bello\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table}
\label{tab:table}
\end{table}

\ctable[
caption = Ctable, label=tab:ctable,]{ll}
{}{
Hello & bello \LL
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\nameref` (and `\autoref`) actually DOES work for table captions.

Comment: Okay, you are right. Problem is that I am using ctable, where it raises an error. I edited teh original post.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I added a minimal working example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem based on the way how `ctable` wrote the information to the `aux`. There you can find the following relevant line:

```
\newlabel{tab:ctable}{{0.2}{1}{\@ctblcap \relax }{table.0.2}{}}
```

If you use `\nameref{tab:ctable}` the argument `{\@ctblcap \relax }` is called. However the command is undefined and it uses the special character `@`. Based on this information the first quick fix is:

```
\makeatletter
 \def\@ctblcap{Table}
 \nameref{tab:ctable} %error
\makeatother
```

On the other hand you can change the implementation of `ctable`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} %provided \expandonce
\makeatletter
\def\@ctblCaption{
   \ifx\@ctblcap\undefined\let\@ctblcap\@ctblcaption\fi
   \ifx\@ctblcaption\empty\else
      \def\@ctblcaptionarg{\ifx\@ctbllabel\empty\else\label{\@ctbllabel}\fi
         \@ctblcaption\ \@ctblcontinued\strut}
      \ifx\@ctblcap\empty
      \begingroup
        \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\caption[]{\expandonce\@ctblcaptionarg}}
        \x
      \else
      \begingroup
        \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\caption[\expandonce\@ctblcap]%
                                          {\expandonce\@ctblcaptionarg}}
        \x
      \fi
   \fi
}
\makeatother
```

The relevant part are the lines starting with `\edef\x`. E.g.:

```
\begingroup
 \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\caption[]{\expandonce\@ctblcaptionarg}}
\x
```

whereby the original code was:

```
\caption[]{\@ctblcaptionarg}
```

The command `caption` doesn't expand the information of its arguments. So in the `aux` file you have the entry `\@ctblcaptionarg`. Instead of a complete expansion of `\@ctblcaptionarg` I used `\expandonce` which is more robust in this case.

The complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} %DIV, BCOR =Seitenränder
\usepackage[]{ctable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\@ctblCaption{
   \ifx\@ctblcap\undefined\let\@ctblcap\@ctblcaption\fi
   \ifx\@ctblcaption\empty\else
      \def\@ctblcaptionarg{\ifx\@ctbllabel\empty\else\label{\@ctbllabel}\fi
         \@ctblcaption\ \@ctblcontinued\strut}
      \ifx\@ctblcap\empty
      \begingroup
        \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\caption[]{\expandonce\@ctblcaptionarg}}
         \x
      \else
      \begingroup
        \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\caption[\expandonce\@ctblcap]%
                                          {\expandonce\@ctblcaptionarg}}
        \x
      \fi
   \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
\ref{tab:table} %ok
\autoref{tab:table} %ok
\nameref{tab:table} %ok 
\end{verbatim}
\ref{tab:table} %ok
\autoref{tab:table} %ok
\nameref{tab:table} %ok 


\begin{verbatim}
\ref{tab:ctable} %ok
\autoref{tab:ctable} %ok
\nameref{tab:ctable} %error
\end{verbatim}
\ref{tab:ctable} %ok
\autoref{tab:ctable} %ok
\nameref{tab:ctable} %error

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l}
hallo & bello\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table}
\label{tab:table}
\end{table}

\ctable[caption = Ctable, label=tab:ctable,]{ll}{}{
Hello & bello \LL}

\end{document}
```

I think you should write bug report to the author of `ctable`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I sent an email to the author, and linked to this page.